# Is there any way to test Venmo APIs from outside the US or on platforms other than the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, payment, venmo

I need to implement Venmo payment systems in our client's iPhone application. Our client is in the USA, but I'm an offsite developer based outside of the USA.

Is there any way to work with the Venmo APIs from outside of the USA for testing purposes?

Comment: I work at Braintree / Venmo. Can you be more specific about what problem you're having, and what APIs you're integrating against? Is it Braintee's Payment Gateway / Venmo Touch, or the Venmo Payouts API or Venmo API?

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for ur response,

Comment: Actually iam iOS Appication developer, i didn't have brief idea about Venmo payment system.But according my client requirement i need to charge all costs from Venmo Payment system.But when i'm try to signup in venmo, it is showing like "Venmo is not yet available in your area."

Comment: For that i need to integrate Venmo API into my application.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Venmo blocks IP addresses outside of the United States. Use a VPN or proxy to access Venmo from outside the US.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between these three types, "Venmo Touch, or the Venmo Payouts API or Venmo API".

Comment: Sure! Venmo Touch: https://www.braintreepayments.com/venmo-touch

Venmo API: https://developer.venmo.com/docs/faq